# Как в postgreSQL записать символ переноса строки?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Через pgAdmin 4 есть таблица постов. Соответственно в одну из колонок записывается содержимое поста. При извлечении и выводе элемента на страницу все переводы на новую строку игнорируются и все отдельные пункты склеиваются в один сплошной неудобочитаемый текст. Как это можно исправить, чтобы сноски не терялись? Есть ли специальный синтаксис переноса строки в postgres?

Comment: думаю, текст постов у тебя редактируется в обычной textarea, по этому при выводе заменяй перенос строки на тег `<br>`.

Comment: Решила проблему немного по-другому, но благодаря вашей наводке с использованием тега. Текст поста в базе данных у меня хранился в переменной типа text, и я туда добавила в нужных местах <br>. Для рендера страниц у меня используется express-handlebars, и чтобы при передаче переменной content с моим текстом на страницу теги не выводились, а обрабатывались, надо было content мне обернуть в три фигурные скобки вместо двух.
В общем, как-то так наконец заработало. Большое спасибо Вам за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью escape-последовательности:

```
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(t.param, E'\n') params
...
```

Группируемые колонки будут склеены с помощью переноса строки.

Подробности смотрите здесь:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html
(п. п. 4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-style Escapes).